# cmake error when compiling with arm-linux-android standalone toolchain but make can not be executed

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I want to compile a native code writing by C with a arm-linux-android Compiler from android-ndk, so that that codes can be executed in a android pad. 
First I write a Toolchain_armgcc_android.cmake. In this file i have put the codes

```
set(CMAKE_STRIP arm-linux-androideabi-strip)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-androideabi-cpp)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/name/tmp/my-android-toolchain)
```

Then write a CMAKE with the codes unders

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/Toolchain-armgcc-android.cmake -DBUILD_EXAMPLESERVER=On -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python ..
```

It is executed and the follows codes was come out,

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/name/tmp/my-android-toolchain   /bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/name/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.9.1") 
-- Git version: v0.1.0-RC4-31-g1a03d02-dirty
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not given; setting to 'RelWithDebInfo'.
-- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

 PYTHON_EXECUTABLE


 - Build files have been written to: /home/name/open62541/build
```

in the same file i wrote a command ,make,. Then the errors come out, like

can anyone tall me the reasons? thanks a lot in advance`

Comment: What error is generated by the build?

Comment: Did you change your directory?